# Why does Python know the answer is alphabetically correct using the following code?

Tags: python, substring, alphabetical

I came upon this problem at the Introduction to computer Science and Programming using Python:

> Assume s is a string of lower case characters.
>
> Write a program that prints the longest substring of s in which the letters occur in alphabetical order. For example, if `s = 'azcbobobegghakl'`, then your program should print: Longest substring in alphabetical order is: beggh.
>
> In the case of ties, print the first substring. For example, if `s = 'abcbcd'`, then your program should print: Longest substring in alphabetical order is: abc.

I have already read a lot of answers (codes) about this problem. I can say that I understand the logic behind those answers.

**However, what I can't comprehend is that "How does Python know the answer is alphabetically correct?"**

Just for reference, the following is a correct code I saw online:

```
s = "azcbobobegghakl"  
longest = current = s[0]

for i in range (len(s) - 1):

        if s[i+1] >= s[i]:
            current += s[i+1]
            if len(current) > len(longest):
                longest = current
        else:
            current = s[i+1]

    print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is:", longest)
```

Again, I understand the logic behind the code. What I don't is how does Python know the answer is alphabetically correct.

*I know this may be a silly question. But as I am a newbie in Programming, the answer to this question means a lot to me.*

Comment: Why do you need sorting?, if you sort the string in alphabetical order, the Longest substring in alphabetical order will be the sorted string itself. Read the question once again the longest substring is `azcbobo[beggh]akl`

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean "understand the logic behind those answers". As your example is just a normal common simple solution.

Comment: Hi, now I look at my question, it was poorly worded. What I meant was how does Python know that the answer is alphabetically correct.

Answer (score 1):

In this code, the condition

```
if s[i+1] >= s[i]
```

compares two characters. In python, when you compare two characters, you are comparing their's ascii code. As you can see [here](https://ascii.cl/), characters are arranged alphabetically in the ascii table.

If it is arranged alphabetically, it is added to the possible solution. In other case, it just create a new possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

The program keeps track of the longest alphabetical substring it has found so far (variable `longest`). When it finds a new one that is longer than the one it already knows (`current`), it remembers that one instead (`longest = current`).

Comment: Hi, now I look at my question, it was poorly worded. What I meant was how does Python know that the answer is alphabetically correct.

Comment: Because character `i+1` (the next character) is greater than character `i` (the current character).